# Equal throws with a pair of dice

Tags: probability

I stumbled upon two questions which can be solved by using same logic.

**1.** Two persons each makes a single throw with a pair of dice.  The probability that the throws are unequal

**Solution:** As the out comes change form 2 to 12 while rolling two dice and total ways where both person get the same number is given by ${1^2}$ + ${2^2}$ + ${3^2}$ + ${4^2}$ + ${5^2}$ + ${6^2}$ + ${5^2}$ + ${4^2}$ + ${3^2}$ + ${2^2}$ + ${1^2}$ = 146.

So required probability = $1 - \dfrac{{146}}{{{6^4}}}$

Recently, I came across a different solution using polynomial functions given below in the image. Can anyone suggest a simple reading to convert a problem into polynomial functions?

[image]

I am unable to understand this part: How the number of favourable ways equal to the constant term in the above solution?  and how this expression came?

$\left( {\dfrac{{{a_2}}}{{{x^2}}} + \dfrac{{{a_3}}}{{{x^3}}} + ... + \dfrac{{{a_{12}}}}{{{x^{12}}}}} \right)$

**2.** Tickets from 0000 to 9999 are kept in a box.  A ticket is lucky if the sum of the first two digits of the ticket is equal to last two digits.  What is the probability of getting a lucky ticket?

**Solution :** Total chances are getting lucky number = $2 \times $( ${1^2}$ + ${2^2}$ + ${3^2}$ + ${4^2}$ + ${5^2}$ + ${6^2}$ + ${7^2}$ + ${8^2}$ + ${9^2}$ ) + ${10^2}$ = 676
Required probability = $\dfrac{{676}}{{{{10}^4}}}$

[image]

Comment: Just to know, from what book is this problem?

Comment: @Masacroso http://www.amazon.in/Textbook-ALGEBRA-JEE-Main-Advanced/dp/9350944901/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1474950026&sr=1-5&keywords=arihant+books+for+iit-jee

Answer (score 1):

Since $$(x+x^2+\cdots + x^6)^2 = a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots + a_{12}x^{12}$$ replacing $x$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ in the above, we get 
$$(1/x+1/x^2+\cdots + 1/x^6)^2 = a_2/x^2+a_3/x^3+\cdots + a_{12}/x^{12}$$
When we multiply the above two, constant term occurs when we multiply $a_i x^i$ by $a_i/x_i$ and hence is 
$$a_2^2+a_3^2 + \cdots + a_{12}^2$$

Comment: My concern is why we have to find the constant term. I understand that the first person sum of throws can be indicated by the polynomial, ${\left( {x + {x^2} + ... + {x^6}} \right)^2}$ = ${a_2}{x^2} + {a_3}{x^3} + ... + {a_{12}}{x^{12}}$ but the same should be true for the second person.  Why why we are taking the second person equation as, ${(1/x + 1/{x^2} +  \cdots  + 1/{x^6})^2} = {a_2}/{x^2} + {a_3}/{x^3} +  \cdots  + {a_{12}}/{x^{12}}$ and why the constant term in the product gives the answer? I would like to know why we are doing this?

Comment: We know that the number of favorable cases is $a_2^2+a_3^2+\cdots +a_{12}^2$. This is same as the constant term in the expression. Computing the constant term is easy using this technique.